# i want try fullpage scrol 100vh

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular6

i want to try fullpage scroll 100vh on every scroll event but 
its showing an error Property 'detail' and wheelDelta does not exist on type 'Event' in this line
if (e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0)

my about.ts file are

```
      ngOnInit() {

         // snapy fullpage scroll

      $(document).ready(function () {
        var divs = $('.mydiv');
        var dir = 'up'; // wheel scroll direction
        var div = 0; // current div
        $(document.body).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (e) {
            if (e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
                dir = 'down';
            } else {
                dir = 'up';
            }
            // find currently visible div :
            div = -1;
            divs.each(function(i){
                if (div<0 && ($(this).offset().top >= $(window).scrollTop())) {
                    div = i;
                }
            });
            if (dir == 'up' && div > 0) {
                div--;
            }
            if (dir == 'down' && div < divs.length) {
                div++;
            }
            //console.log(div, dir, divs.length);
            $('html,body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: divs.eq(div).offset().top
            }, 200);
            return false;
        });
        $(window).resize(function () {
            $('html,body').scrollTop(divs.eq(div).offset().top);
        });
    });
  }
```

.html file are

```
<div class="mydiv" style="text-align:center; color:green">Gallery</div>
<div class="mydiv" style="background-color: #aaa">Page 1</div>
<div class="mydiv" style="background-color: #444">Page 2</div>
<div class="mydiv" style="background-color: blue">Page 3</div>
<div class="mydiv" style="background-color: #ccc">Page 4</div>
<div class="mydiv" style="background-color: yellow">Page 5</div>
```

.css file are

```
html, body, body>div {
    height:100%;
    color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: Is it about.js or about.ts?

Comment: .ts i doing this in angular6